# Create a List of Grid Points in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a list of grid points in Java.

For example, for a `10x10` grid, this can be done very nicely in Python:

```
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(1, 10, 10), np.linspace(1, 10, 10))
grid = np.dstack((xv, yv)).reshape(-1, 2)
```

Result:

```
array([[  1.,   1.],
       [  2.,   1.],
       [  3.,   1.],
       ..., 
       [  8.,  10.],
       [  9.,  10.],
       [ 10.,  10.]])
```

How could this be done efficiently in "pure" Java?

Comment: Is "efficiency" in terms of lines of code or runtime performance, or you just after an elegant solution? I assume 'pure' means without additional libraries.

Comment: Your result shows `array[100]` not `array[10][10]` but you could simply do it with loops. It could be done with Stream API to but can't help you with that. Don't fool yourself, python probably provide method to do it the same way.

Comment: Of course, I'm aware of the fact that I can't completely avoid loops when porting to Java. However, I need a  "scalable" solution since in practice my grid will be about `1000x1000`. So @Adam I'm looking for the best solution in terms of runtime performance (elegance would be a nice plus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to modify the list after generation you could do it much more efficiently using an object.

```
class GridPoints {
    private final int size;

    public GridPoints(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int[] get(int i) {
        return new int[] {
                (i % size) + 1,
                (i / size) + 1
        };
    }
}

public void test() {
    GridPoints g = new GridPoints(10);
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g.get(i)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not necessarily convinced it will be much more efficient. At least not if you need to query each grid point many times since you create a new array each time.

Comment: The *space* efficiency is unsurpassed.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be with plain arrays:

```
int[][] array = new int[100][];

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = new int[] {i % 10 + 1, i / 10 + 1};
}
```

You might want to change `int[][] array = new int[100][];` to `double[][] array = new double[100][];`.

Tested your python code, this code gives the exact same output.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/szFYVc)

Comment: Nice and simple.

Answer (score -1):

```
int x = 1;
for(in i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++){
        numbers[i][j] = x;
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why starting from 1?

Comment: Yes, but array indexes start from 0.

Comment: And BTW this is completely different from the output shown in the question. http://ideone.com/P34DXs

Comment: How should the array be declared?

Comment: I noticed your answer got downvoted, @DeepeshChoudhary. How could that be? A possible explanation could be, when I correct `in` to `int` I get `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, …, 90], [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]`. I don’t think this was what was asked for.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.